# Sub Query Not IN With Left Join Alternative?

Tags: mysql

I have Query Like This

```
SELECT  f.ACCOUNT_ID,
        f.TGL,
        p.ACCOUNT_EMAILADDRESS


     FROM distributor_kokola.forecast f
      inner join distributor_kokola.push_distributor p on p.ACCOUNT_ID = f.ACCOUNT_ID
      where f.ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN(

                 select ACCOUNT_ID
                        from distributor_kokola.forecast
                         where DATE_FORMAT(TGL, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m")  
                         group by ACCOUNT_ID


    )

      group by f.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

That Sub Query work but To Slow so I change it with Left Join, it work faster

```
SELECT  f.ACCOUNT_ID,
        f.TGL,
        p.ACCOUNT_EMAILADDRESS


     FROM distributor_kokola.forecast f
       left  join(

                 select ACCOUNT_ID
                        from distributor_kokola.forecast
                         where DATE_FORMAT(TGL, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m")  
                         group by ACCOUNT_ID


    )subb on subb.ACCOUNT_ID = f.ACCOUNT_ID

       inner join distributor_kokola.push_distributor p on p.ACCOUNT_ID = f.ACCOUNT_ID
      group by f.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

But, My issue is  Still Contain wrong Result,

With Not IN, query 1 select where NOT IN query 2.

How can I get like NOT IN query with left join.

Can Anyone Help Me?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a WHERE clause to filter by the results of your `LEFT JOIN`. If you add an appropriate WHERE clause `WHERE subb.ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL`, it should work as expected (since you used a `GROUP BY` in your subquery, there's no danger of duplicate rows):

```
SELECT  f.ACCOUNT_ID,
        f.TGL,
        p.ACCOUNT_EMAILADDRESS
     FROM distributor_kokola.forecast f
       left  join(
                 select ACCOUNT_ID
                        from distributor_kokola.forecast
                         where DATE_FORMAT(TGL, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m")  
                         group by ACCOUNT_ID
    )  subb on subb.ACCOUNT_ID = f.ACCOUNT_ID
       inner join distributor_kokola.push_distributor p on p.ACCOUNT_ID = f.ACCOUNT_ID
      WHERE sub.ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL
      group by f.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

**Update**

The goal of our `LEFT JOIN` is to find all rows in our `forecast` table that don't have a matching row in the subquery. Therefore, we need a `WHERE` clause that removes all rows with a matching row - `WHERE sub.ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL` fits quite nicely.

SO user @quassnoi has written a [wonderful comparison of different methods](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) to achieve this goal.

Comment: Hey its Work Like A charm, But I still Dont Get it, why "WHERE subb.ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL"?

Comment: Dear @Uchsun try to learn left join with small table then you will get easily

Comment: @Uchsun I've updated my answer and added a short explanation. Hopefully, it's clearer now.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thanks A Lot, I Understand Now.